# Is there an analytic approximation of the following function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory, analytic-functions

Let $\psi$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying

1. $\phi(x)\geq 0$ for any $x$ and $\psi(x)=0$ when $|x|\geq 1$.
2. $\int_{-1}^1\psi(x)dx=1$
3. $\int_{-1}^1x\psi(x)=0$.
4. $|\psi'''(x)|\leq B$ for a constant $B$ any $x$.

It is not hard to find a function in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ satisfying these conditions. For instance 
$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}Ce^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}~\mbox{if $|x|<1$}\\
0~\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
where $C$ is a normalizer.

My question is whether it is possible to find an analytical function meeting all the conditions or find a sequence of analytic functions $\{\phi_n\}_n$ approximating $\psi$ in the sense that $\sup\{|\phi_n(x)-\psi(x)|:x\in\mathbb{R}\}\rightarrow 0(n\rightarrow\infty)$. Moreoever, $|\phi_n'''(x)|\leq B'$ for some constant $B'$.

Comment: A nonzero analytic function cannot have compact support, so that destroys that idea. Also recall that if a sequence of analytic functions converges uniformly on compact subsets then the limit is analytic again.

Comment: Somehow $\phi(x)$ crept in there.

Comment: @Ian Your last line fails on the real line (vs the complex plane).

Comment: @zhw. Quite true! I should have been explicit in saying "complex analytic" in the second case (it is not necessary in the first case). Along these lines, to user07001129: I suspect Weierstrass's theorem (applied to your bump function $\psi$) achieves your second idea, though I am not sure whether the third derivative estimate is easy to check.

Comment: Look at $\psi \ast n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$ where $\ast$ is the convolution. You'll get a sequence of analytic functions converging uniformly to $\psi$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user1952009 Could you elaborate your answer in more detail? Why does it converge to $\psi$? Why is it analytic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\psi \in C^0_c(\mathbb{R})$  then $$\psi_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(y) n e^{- \pi n^2 (x-y)^2}dy$$ is analytic because $e^{- x^2}$ is,

and it converges uniformly to $\psi$ because by uniform continuity $|\psi(x+y)-\psi(x)|\le g(y)$ where $g$ is continuous, bounded and $g(0) = 0$ so that
$$|\psi(x) - \psi_n(x)| \le 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x-y)-\psi(x)| n e^{- \pi n^2 y^2}dy \le \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y/n)  e^{- \pi y^2}dy$$